# Summarising wind vector statistics over time

Tags: algorithms, python, descriptive-statistics

My problem is to figure out an algorithm for summarising wind statistics over an area. The statistics are (24x) hourly but I want to end up with 2-3 'blocks' that summarise the conditions for the whole day.

My data is in the form of separate magnitude and direction NumPy arrays but I could convert them to u,v or polar coordinates or whatever if it made the solution easier.

There are other conditions like: each block must be at least 3 hours long, but the general problem is the trade off between accuracy and precision. And in a way, to maximise the similarity of the statistics inside each 'block' and the difference between each 'block'.

Anyway I don't have a background in statistics and am wondering if there is an array-based approach I could use, maybe involving calculating minimum bounding box/convex hull, that kind of thing?

I'm not looking for a complete algorithm but some hints as to what I should be searching for to do further research.